# Bilinear pairings / map exercise

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an exercise I have to solve for a work sheet but I can't ask tutors about it. Now I'm struggling trying to come up with anything. The exercise is as follows:

Let u be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We define a map $\phi_u$: $\mathbb{R}^3$ × $\mathbb{R}^3$ $\to \mathbb{R}$ as follows. Given a pair of vectors $(v, w)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we let $\phi_u(v, w)$ be the determinant of the endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3$
sending $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$ to $u$, $v$ and $w$ respectively.

$(1)$ Assume that $u = (a, b, c)$. Show that

$\phi_u = \left(\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1\\
    x_2\\
    x_3\\
    \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
    y_1\\
    y_2\\
    y_3\\
    \end{bmatrix} \right) =$   det$\begin{bmatrix}
    a & x_1 & y_1 \\
    b & x_2 & y_2 \\
    c & x_3 & y_3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

$(2)$ Deduce that $\phi_u$ is an alternating bilinear pairing.

$(3)$ What are the left and right kernels of $\phi_u$?

I'm struggling to come up with anything for this other than the fact that for $(2)$, alternating means symmetric so if $\phi_u(m, m_0) = \phi_u(m_0, m)$ resp. $\phi_u(m, m_0) = -\phi_u(m_0, m)$ for all $m$,$ m_0 \in M$ , although I do not quite know how to apply it in this case.

Comment: What is the matrix of the endomorphism that sends $e_1,e_2,e_3$ to $u,v,w$? Isn't it just the matrix with $u,v,w$ as its columns? Can you use the fact the determinant is alternating and multilinear? Do you know the definitions of left and right kernel?

Comment: Alternating doesn't mean symmetric. We say that a bilinear map $b$ is *alternating* if $b(v,v) = 0$ for all $v$.

Comment: @azif00 That's odd. I just took it right from our definitions and it said that a bilinear pairing is said to be symmetric / alternating if the above mentioned definition holds. Maybe its a translation error?

Comment: @runway44 I'm not quite sure what you mean with the determinant being alternating and multilinear. Based of my script, the left kernel is just the kernel of the transpose of a matrix. The right kernel is just the "normal" kernel. So I just transpose it, and calculate from there? Or is there an additional step required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detailed version

(1) Let $\psi:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be the endomorphism defined on the basis $\mathcal{B}=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ by $\psi(e_1)=u,\psi(e_2)=v,\psi(e_3)=w$. By definition
$$\phi_u(v,w)=\det(\psi).$$
We have $u=(a,b,c)^T$ and we can assume $v=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T,w=(y_1,y_2,y_3)^T$. Representing $\psi$ in the standard basis $\mathcal{B}$ in source and target we get the matrix
$$\psi_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B}}=\begin{pmatrix}a&x_1&y_1\\b&x_2&y_2\\c&x_3&y_3\end{pmatrix}.$$
It is a standard fact of the representation of linear selfmaps by matrices in the same basis in source and target that $\det(\psi)=\det(\psi_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B}})$. Thus
$$\phi_u\left(\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\y_3\end{pmatrix}\right)=\phi_u(v,w)=\det(\psi)=\det(\psi_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B}})=\det\begin{pmatrix}a&x_1&y_1\\b&x_2&y_2\\c&x_3&y_3\end{pmatrix}.$$

(2) There are several parts. First show that $\phi_u$ is a bilinear pairing, i.e. that it is linear in its first and second argument. Second show that this pairing is alternating.

Using [well known properties of the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Characterization_of_the_determinant) (property (2), the determinent is multilinear) this is immediate.

Alternatively this can be done by direct computation. For this let $v'=(x_1',x_2',x_3')^T,w'=(y_1',y_2',y_3')^T$ be additional vectors and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
\phi_u(v+v',w)=\det\begin{pmatrix}a&x_1+x_1'&y_1\\b&x_2+x_2'&y_2\\c&x_3+x_3'&y_3\end{pmatrix}=\\
a(x_2+x_2')y_3+(x_1+x_1')y_2c+y_1b(x_3+x_3')-y_1(x_2+x_2')c-(x_1+x_1')by_3-ay_2(x_3+x_3')=\\
ax_2y_3+x_1y_2c+y_1bx_3-y_1x_2c-x_1by_3-ay_2x_3 \ \ \ + \ \ \ 
ax_2'y_3+x_1'y_2c+y_1bx_3'-y_1x_2'c-x_1'by_3-ay_2x_3'=\\
\det\begin{pmatrix}a&x_1&y_1\\b&x_2&y_2\\c&x_3&y_3\end{pmatrix}+\det\begin{pmatrix}a&x_1'&y_1\\b&x_2'&y_2\\c&x_3'&y_3\end{pmatrix}=
\phi_u(v,w)+\phi_u(v',w).
$$
$$
\phi_u(\lambda v,w)=\det\begin{pmatrix}a&\lambda x_1&y_1\\b&\lambda x_2&y_2\\c&\lambda x_3&y_3\end{pmatrix}=\\
a(\lambda x_2)y_3+(\lambda x_1)y_2c+y_1b(\lambda x_3)-y_1(\lambda x_2)c-(\lambda x_1)by_3-ay_2(\lambda x_3)=\\
\lambda (ax_2y_3+x_1y_2c+y_1bx_3-y_1x_2c-x_1by_3-ay_2x_3)=\\
\lambda \det\begin{pmatrix}a&x_1&y_1\\b&x_2&y_2\\c&x_3&y_3\end{pmatrix}=
\lambda \phi_u(v,w).
$$
Analog computations yield
$\phi_u(v,w+w')=\phi_u(v,w)+\phi_u(v,w')$ and
$\phi_u(v,\lambda w)=\lambda \phi_u(v,w).$ These four equalities by definition consitute bilinearity.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form#Symmetric,_skew-symmetric_and_alternating_forms) a bilinear form $B$ on a vector space $V$ over a base field $k$ is alternating if and only if
$$\forall v\in V:B(v,v)=0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(A)}$$
and it is symmetric if and only if
$$\forall v,w\in V:B(v,w)=B(w,v). \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(S)}$$
It is also stated that these notions coincide, if $\text{char}(k)\neq 2$. Since for us $k=\mathbb{R}$, we have $\text{char}(k)=0\neq 2$. It will be simpler to work with notion (A) of these two equivalent properties.

One can either work with another [well known property of the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Characterization_of_the_determinant) (property (3) aptly called "alternating") to get for arbitrary $v=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$
$$\phi_u\left(v,v\right)=\det\begin{pmatrix}a&x_1&x_1\\b&x_2&x_2\\c&x_3&x_3\end{pmatrix}=\det\left(u,v,v\right)=0$$
or alternatively use the explicit formula for determinants of 3x3-matrices and a bit of calculation to also arrive at
$$\phi_u\left(v,v\right)=\det\begin{pmatrix}a&x_1&x_1\\b&x_2&x_2\\c&x_3&x_3\end{pmatrix}=ax_2x_3+x_1x_2c+x_1bx_3-x_1x_2c-x_1bx_3-ax_2x_3=0.$$
We see that in both cases using propositions about abstract properties (of determinants) is much more elegant and lucid than brute force computations, but outcomes are equivalent.

(3) Set $$\phi_{u,L}:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\left(\mathbb{R}^3\right)^*,v\mapsto\left[\phi_{u,L}(v):\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R},w\mapsto\phi_u(v,w)\right]$$ and analogously set $\phi_{u,R}$. Left and right kernels are
$$
\ker_L\phi_u=\ker\phi_{u,L} \text{ and }
\ker_R\phi_u=\ker\phi_{u,R}.
$$
Since we have seen in (2) that $\phi_u$ is symmetric (equivalently in char$\neq 2$ alternating) we have $\ker_L\phi_u=\ker_R\phi_u$.

By the [alternating property of determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Characterization_of_the_determinant) it follows similarly as above that
$$
\phi_{u,L}(u):\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R},w\mapsto\phi_u(u,w)=\det(u,u,w)=0,
$$
i.e., $\phi_{u,L}(u)$ is the 0-map which is the zero in $\left(\mathbb{R}^3\right)^*$, therefore $u\in\ker_L\phi_u$.

Distinguish two cases. Case A. $u\neq(0,0,0)^T\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and case B. $u=(0,0,0)^T$.

Case A.
By the [Steinitz exchange lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma) we can complete $u$ to a basis $\mathcal{U}=(u,u',u'')$. Let $v\in\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\text{span}(u)$ be arbitrary with a representation in $\mathcal{U}$ as $v=\mu_1u+\mu_2u'+\mu_3u''$. Since $v\not\in\text{span}(u)$ we have $(\mu_2,\mu_3)\neq(0,0)$. Wlog. $\mu_2\neq 0$ (otherwise swap $u'$ and $u''$ in $\mathcal{U}$). We use that the determinant is non-zero on a basis (in particular $\det(\mathcal{U})=\det(u,u',u'')\neq 0$) and [other properties of determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Characterization_of_the_determinant) to show that $\phi_{u,L}(v)\neq 0$.
$$
\left(\phi_{u,L}(v)\right)(u'')=\det(u,v,u'')=\det(u,\mu_1u+\mu_2u'+\mu_3u'',u'')=\\
\mu_1\det(u,u,u'')+
\mu_2\det(u,u',u'')+
\mu_3\det(u,u'',u'')=\\
\mu_1\cdot 0+\mu_2\det(u,u',u'')+\mu_3\cdot 0\neq 0,
$$
where the last inequality followed from $\mu_2\neq 0$ and $\det(u,u',u'')\neq 0$. Now $\left(\phi_{u,L}(v)\right)(u'')\neq 0$ implies $\phi_{u,L}(v)\neq 0$ and therefore $v\not\in\ker_L\phi_u$. Thus in case A. we have $\ker_L\phi_u=\text{span}(u)$.

Case B.
By [yet other properties of the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Immediate_consequences) the determinant is zero, if the columns of an associated matrix are linearly dependent. In case of $u=(0,0,0)^T$ we have a zero column which implies linear dependence. In this case $\phi_{u,L}=\phi_{0,L}=0$ is a zero map, thus $\ker_L\phi_u=\mathbb{R}^3$.

In summary we have
$$
\ker_L\phi_u=\ker_R\phi_u=\begin{cases}\text{span}(u),& \text{ if }u\neq 0\\ \mathbb{R}^3,& \text{ if }u=0.\end{cases}
$$

Again one could use explicit calculations instead of abstract arguments, I only sketch the steps of one possibility. Compute a matrix representing the bilinear form  in the standard basis $\mathcal{B}$ by $A_{i,j}=\phi_u(e_i,e_j)$ (which is justified thanks to the first part of (2)) and get
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}0&c&b\\c&0&a\\b&a&0\end{pmatrix}\text{ with }
\phi_u(v,w)=(x_1,x_2,x_3)A\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\y_3\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This matrix being symmetric is yet a third method to show the second part of (2). Now we can easily compute left and right kernel as usual matrix kernels via
$$
\ker_L\phi_u=\ker A^T
\text{ and }
\ker_R\phi_u=\ker A.
$$
Since $A$ is symmetric the results coincide and since $u=(a,b,c)^T$ depends on three variables, case distinctions are necessary to resolve the two cases A. and B. In the end we get the same results as via the abstract approach.

---

Short version

(1) Clear from the properties of representing linear maps by matrices.

(2) Follows immediately from the properties of the determinant.

(3) By symmetry from (2) and by the properties of determinants it is straight forward to see
$$
\ker_L\phi_u=\ker_R\phi_u=\begin{cases}\text{span}(u),& \text{ if }u\neq 0\\ \mathbb{R}^3,& \text{ if }u=0.\end{cases}
$$